# XPath Select Attribute Values from Parent AND Child Nodes

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Following is my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:lang="en-GB">
      <results>

        <sector sectorid="1" sectorname="Basic Materials">
          <industry id="112" name="Agricultural Chemicals"/>
          <industry id="132" name="Aluminum"/>
          <industry id="110" name="Chemicals - Major Diversified"/>
          <industry id="131" name="Copper"/>
          <industry id="134" name="Gold"/>
          <industry id="121" name="Independent Oil and Gas"/>
          <industry id="120" name="Major Integrated Oil and Gas"/>
        </sector>

        <sector sectorid="2" sectorname="Conglomerates">
          <industry id="210" name="Conglomerates"/>
        </sector>

        <sector sectorid="7" sectorname="Services">
          <industry id="720" name="Advertising Agencies"/>
          <industry id="773" name="Air Delivery and Freight Services"/>
          <industry id="772" name="Air Services and Others"/>
          <industry id="730" name="Apparel Stores"/>
          <industry id="744" name="Auto Dealerships"/>
        </sector>

     </results>
   </query>
```

From the above XML file, I am looking to store the values of attributes: `sectorid`, `id`, and `name` in the appropriate variables (I'm using Java). I have been looking at different XPath expressions and I came up with the following code, however, a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` exception is thrown when storing the value of `id` attribute. Here's my code:

```
public class XMLToDatabase {

    private static int __SectorID;
    private static int __IndustryID;
    private static String __IndustryName;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, UnsupportedEncodingException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

        try {               
            File _XMLFile = new File("SectorsAndIndustries.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory _DocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            _DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

            DocumentBuilder _DocumentBuilder = _DocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document _Document = _DocumentBuilder.parse(_XMLFile);  

            _Document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            XPath _XPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            XPathExpression _XPathExpression = _XPath.compile("//sector | //industry");

            NodeList _NodeList = (NodeList) _XPathExpression.evaluate(_Document, XPathConstants.NODESET);


            for (int i = 0; i < _NodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node _Node = _NodeList.item(i);

                if(_Node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element _Element = (Element) _Node;

                    __SectorID = Integer.parseInt(_Element.getAttribute("sectorid"));
                    __IndustryID = Integer.parseInt(_Element.getAttribute("id"));
                    __IndustryName = _Element.getAttribute("name");
                }

            System.out.println(__SectorID + ", " + __IndustryID + ", " + __IndustryName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Could someone please help me determine if it is the `XPath Expression` that I am making a mistake with, or if is the way I am storing the second variable `__IndustryID`? Because the first variable `__SectorID` correctly stores the value `1`, but throws the above mentioned exception for `__IndustryID`. Ideally, I would want to store the values of all 3 attributes every time the `for` loop is executed, to save them to a database table. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: This simple XPath 2.0 expression produces the wanted results -- you need just to understand what is being done and to translate this to Java and evaluating multiple times an XPath expression -- for each `industry` element: `//sector/industry/concat(../@sectorid, ' ', @id, ' ', @name, codepoints-to-string((10)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathias has suggested the right approach, and I have come up with a solution for it with slight modifications:

```
public class XMLToDatabase {

    private static int __SectorID;
    private static int __IndustryID;
    private static String __IndustryName;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

        try {
            File _XMLFile = new File("C:/Users/Sachin/Desktop/SectorsAndIndustries.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory _DocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder _DocumentBuilder = _DocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document _Document = _DocumentBuilder.parse(_XMLFile);
            _Document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            XPath _XPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            NodeList _NodeList1 = (NodeList) _XPath.evaluate("/results/sector", _Document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            for (int i = 0; i < _NodeList1.getLength(); i++) {
                Element _Element1 = (Element) _NodeList1.item(i);

                __SectorID = Integer.parseInt(_Element1.getAttribute("sectorid"));

                NodeList _NodeList2 = (NodeList) _XPath.evaluate("industry", _Element1, XPathConstants.NODESET);

                for (int k=0; k < _NodeList2.getLength(); k++) {
                    __IndustryID = Integer.parseInt(_XPath.evaluate("industry[position()=" + (k + 1) + "]/@id", _Element1));
                    __IndustryName = _XPath.evaluate("industry[position()=" + (k + 1) + "]/@name", _Element1);

                    System.out.println(__SectorID + ", " + __IndustryID + ", " + __IndustryName);
                }
                System.out.println("\n-----------\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you are compiling a node list with nodes that are either `sector` or `industry` elements. For each of those, you'd like to retrieve the `sectorid` and `id` attributes - but, obviously, no element has both of those attributes.

A better approach would be to

- find all `sector` elements and for each of those print out the sector ID
- for each `sector` element go through all its child elements called `industry` (this requires applying a second XPath expression to each `sector` element, but it's a trivial one: `"industry"`)
- and output the ID attribute of each `industry`